ROS 2 nav2 geotiff / geo-referenced costmap
We are working with various GNSS-based outdoor AMRs and vehicles and have recently switched to nav2 (and opennav_coverage to be precise) for navigation.
Now, I do have static global costmaps that are shared between robots and are generally stored as geotiff files in a global SRS. I am currently planning to write a wrapper around the nav2_map_server that processes these maps, computes the origin of the map in the map frame and feeds the results to the map server. We currently initialise the map frame at runtime (r__l navsat_transform wait_for_datum=false).
I wanted to make sure that I didn't simply miss a package or functionality that already exists (I am somewhat surprised I couldn't find it so far).
So if you know of any package/node that does this, or have any suggestions regarding the implementation of it, let me know!
